# jdbcTemplate parameter array not worked

Tags: spring-data-jpa

```
   String sql_query_main_product = "SELECT pack_code FROM PACKAGE_DETAILS WHERE pack_code = 'ABC' ";

   String output = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql_query_main_product, String.class);

     log.info(output);
```

This is working and return 'ABC'

But

```
String sql_query_main_product = "SELECT pack_code FROM MOBIS_PACKAGE_DETAILS WHERE pack_code = ? ";

Object[] objects = new Object[]{"ABC"};

String output = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql_query_main_product,objects, String.class);
```

This is not working

What is the reason?

Comment: web logic server

Comment: Oracle Database

Comment: The problem was resolved, Column type of the given column was char